# Why cant I post-increment a function call c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants, post-increment

Lets say I have this array and function

```
int a[] = {1,2};

const int * bar() {
    return a;
}
```

Then in main

```
int main() {
    const int * p1 = bar()++;
}
```

Why does this throw a compiler error? In my thinking it would return a const int pointer to a and then the post increment operator would move the pointer over to the second element in a.

```
test.cpp:14:25: error: lvalue required as increment operand


14 |     const int * p1 = bar()++;
```

Comment: Please always include the actual compiler error when asking about errors

Comment: Probably because returned values are rvalues not lvalues. Just do `p1 = bar()+1`

Comment: The message says it clearly. You need an lvalue while the function returns an rvalue. The same would occur trying bar()= ...

Comment: you should not save address of non-constant value to pointer to constant value, discouraged

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt why would that be discouraged? It makes sense to have a `const` pointer or reference to something you don't plan to modify

Comment: 1.) you dont have a constant pointer, you have a pointer pointing to a const value and you array is not a constant value. But you are quite right you can plan not to change it with the pointer ...

Comment: Why would you want to post-increment a temporary pointer?

Comment: You should re-pose your question with pre-increment instead of post-increment. Even if a post-increment was accepted in this code, it would be a no-op. The post-increment says to store the returned value in `p1` *then* increment (and discard) the returned value. The value stored in `p1` would still be what was returned (`a`). A pre-increment, on the other hand, would say to increment then store, that is put `a+1` in `p1`, if it compiled. You get the same compilation error either way, but at least pre-increment asks for a meaningful effect.